# Tool to compare DB Structure MS ACCESS vs SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, compare

I recently migrated a MS Access database to SQL Server, mostly was imported just fine, but there are some datatype differences that I would like to find with some tool if available.

Tools I found so far compare MS Access against MS Access, or SQL Server vs SQL Server only.

Comment: Don't know about comparison, but for database migration you can check you ispirer.

Answer (score 0):

At issue is that Access (or JET Red) does not have a single canonical API for working with its data-model, instead you mostly go through the OLE-DB driver or the ODBC driver. I think (but cannot confirm) that the Office Access GUI program *probably* its own internal API that bypasses the OLE-DB or ODBC abstractions, unfortunately the GUI program does not use specific technical terminology in things like the Table Designer (e.g. `Number > Integer` doesnt say if it's a 16, 32 or 64-bit integer, and `Number > Replication ID` is not a number at all but a Win32 GUID).

As of 2019, Microsoft has seemingly *de-prioritized* OLE-DB compared to the lower-level ODBC API for JET Red, but that's okay because ODBC still provides us with the necessary details for determining a database table's design.

Anyway - the good news is that you don't necessarily need a tool to compare an Access (JET Red) database with a SQL Server database because it's easy to get the ODBC table specifications yourself.

Something like this:

```
Dictionary<String,DataTable> jetTables = new Dictionary<String,DataTable>();

using( OleDbConnection jetConnection = new OleDbConnection( "your-access-connection-string") )
{
    await jetConnection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    DataTable schemaTable = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(
        OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,
        new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" }
    );

    foreach( DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() )
    {
        String tableName = (String)row.ItemArray[2];

        DataTable tableSchema = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(
            OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,
            new object[] { null, null, tableName, "TABLE" }
        );

        jetTables.Add( tableName, tableSchema );
    } 
}

Dictionary<String,DataTable> sqlTables = new Dictionary<String,DataTable>();

using( SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection( "your-sql-server-connection-string" ) )
{
    await sqlConnection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    DataTable allTables = new DataTable();
    using( SqlCommand cmd1 = sqlConnection.CreateCommand() )
    {
        cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";

        using( SqlDataReader rdr1 = await cmd1.ExecuteReaderAsync.ConfigureAwait(false) )
        {
            allTables.Load( rdr1 );
        }
    }

    foreach( DataRow row in allTables.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() )
    {
        String tableName = (String)row.ItemArray[0];

        using( SqlCommand cmd2 = sqlConnection.CreateCommand() )
        {
            cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName";
            cmd2.Parameters.Add( "@tableName", SqlDbType.NVarChar ).Value = tableName;

            using( SqlDataReader rdr2 = await cmd2.ExecuteReaderAsync.ConfigureAwait(false) )
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load( rdr2 );
                sqlTables.Add( tableName, dt );
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Then compare `jetTables` with `sqlTables` as you so wish.